# Sonata Project: an admin service for multiple entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a doctrine Inheritance and I don't know how to manage it with Sonata

My parent

```
/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"abstract_page" = "AbstractPage", "content_page" = "ContentPage"})
 */
abstract class AbstractPage
{
    protected $name
}
```

One of the children

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="content_page")
 */
class ContentPage extends AbstractPage
{
    protected $content;
}
```

Can I have a add button for each child but only a list view with all my entities which extends AbstractPage and when I select one of the page I need to have the view or the edit of the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some advanced features from Sonata Admin. To read about them, please go to: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-1/doc/reference/advance.html, specially "16.3. INHERITED CLASSES". This way you will have Add Buttons and create/edit views for each of your subclasses.